# What is the password for Subversion in local Repository using Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, svn, passwords, localhost

I want to use Subversion (SVN) in Android Studio. 
I read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc.tbl-1) then I want to use my local repository (localhost), so I set the URL: "**file:///localhost/svn**". (I also try  "**http://127.0.0.1/svn**")

[image]

I click Checkout and get this:

[image]

So is it possible to use localhost as SVN repository?

What is the password for this local repository SVN? How to find it?

Comment: when you set up your svn server you can also set up users and password. the password is user related and you should have defined it

Comment: Read up-to-date SVNBook 1.8: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a week I was looking for a solution, I've found [Visual SVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/) to create the Users & Password

Answer (score 1):

The URL `file:///localhost/svn` is invalid. `file://` access URL is used to specify local resource and it should include local path such as e.g. `file:///C:/Repositories/MyRepo` on Windows. I don't understand why you enter localhost in local file path.

Read [SVNBook | Addressing the Repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.advanced.reposurls) carefully.

Ask your colleagues for advise and proper repository URL.